# Is there a way to write this Cron command succinctly?

Tags: bash, cron

I wand to add this to the crontab 
    `3,8,13,18,23,28,33,38,43,48 * * * * foo.sh`.
Is there a way to write this in a less verbose manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
3-48/5 * * * * foo.sh
```

should do the trick

Comment: That syntax is specific to the Vixie implementation of `cron. It's likely, but not certain, that your system supports it. `man 5 crontab` to be sure; read the syntax description, and look for Paul Vixie's name at the bottom of the man page.